# angular search bar this.items.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, angular, searchbar

I am fetching data from a JSON file that's stored locally .The JSON string is an array of locations cities names .

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "city": {
          "cityname": {
            "id": "الموصل"
          },
          "coords": {
            "long": 43.129,
            "lat": 36.342
          }
        }
      },
          {
        "city": {
          "cityname": {
            "id": "بغداد"
          },
          "coords": {
            "long": 43.129,
            "lat": 36.342
          }
        }
      }

    ]
  }
```

i have response in html . and all data arrays are showing , but when i searching on any city name in box search i get error :

```
 ERROR TypeError: this.items.filter is not a function
    at Tab1Page.push../src/app/tab1/tab1.page.ts.Tab1Page.getItems (tab1.page.ts:74)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (Tab1Page.html:35)
    at handleEvent (core.js:23106)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24176)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23903)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:20555)
    at core.js:21002
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17289)
```

code :

```
 items:any


constructor() {

    this.initializeItems()

}

initializeItems() {


  this.items ={
    "data": [
      {
        "city": {
          "cityname": {
            "id": "الموصل"
          },
          "coords": {
            "long": 43.129,
            "lat": 36.342
          }
        }
      },
          {
        "city": {
          "cityname": {
            "id": "بغداد"
          },
          "coords": {
            "long": 43.129,
            "lat": 36.342
          }
        }
      }

    ]
  }
}


getItems(ev: any) {
  // Reset items back to all of the items
  this.initializeItems();

  // set val to the value of the searchbar
  const val = ev.target.value;

  // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
  if (val && val.trim() != '') {
    this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
      item["data"].city.cityname.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
      console.log(item)
    })
  }
}
```

Html

```
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items.data">
      {{ item.city.cityname.id}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

any idea please ?

Comment: @Vega is it duplicate

Comment: Of course it is :) It's javascript

Comment: @Vega i didn't see any duplicate in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780950/why-does-console-tell-me-that-filter-is-not-a-function

Comment: Because .filter was applied on the non-array object in both cases. If tis wasn't a duplicate, it would be closed as "Cannot reproduce". I didn't downvote though

Comment: :/ . but the answers still not fix my question

Comment: Do you have the same error message? If the answer is no, then you have a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change :

```
this.items.filter
```

to :

```
this.items.data.filter
```

As `this.items` is `JSON` object and filter function expects array to be filtered

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter-data-demo)** ( with filter function bugs solving )

Comment: okay but when i enter city name he doesn't filter it ! . all cities names are hide when i write any of city name !

Comment: Change `item["data"].city.cityname` to `item.city.cityname` @AliGhassan

Comment: l did like that but he still all cities names are hide when i write any of city name ! `item.city.cityname.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
      console.log(item.city.cityname.id)
    })`

Comment: @AliGhassan, there are lots of flow issues in your code, please check working demo linked in answer and also user filter pipe instead of function, this way you dont have to handle 2 arrays as I did in my code

Answer (score 2):

in your getItems function

`this.items.filter((item) => {`
should be

`this.items.data.filter((item) => {`

as filter is expecting an array.

Comment: okay but when i enter city name he doesn't filter it ! . all cities names are hide when i write any of city name !

Comment: he backs all arrays when i searched

Comment: @Ali check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468805/custom-filter-search-in-angular-5